# Cast int to unsigned int c++

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, uint32-t

What is the best casting method to use when casting int to uint32_t?

Should I use `(uint32_t)num`, or `reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(num)`, or `static_cast<uint32_t>(num)`? (Or something else)?

I know that there are many explanations out there regards the different casting types, but I want to ask specifically about primitive types.

Comment: What do you want to happen if `num` is negative?

Comment: @NathanOliver - in my specific use case I can assume it won't be negative (means the result can be undefined)